# Drupal 7 - Getting data from webservice just for presentation

Tags: web-services, drupal-7

I have a use case where I have to consume the data from the some web service. I don't have to store that data on Drupal database, but I might cache(optional) and present the data on the browser. Drupal is just a interface between the webservice and client browser. I was looking on the modules that can be used to handle the remote activities including "Remote entity", "Feeds". But I think those modules are overkill just for getting data and rendering on the browser and also I think I had to store data on drupal with those modules. Basically I am looking for some module that will just get the data on realtime from webservice and I could use that and present that to browser on same http request.

Otherwise I am ready and set to jot down custom module!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Install webservices module and create the custom module for getting the results for example showing the albums photo...or if you use view in drupal then services view module is good with services module..

Answer (score 0):

You can create menu items in custom module's hook_menu like following

```
$menu_items['web-service-path'] = array(
    'title' => 'web service title',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver', // Will make sure that complete drupal bootstrap does not load and only service code runs.
    'page callback' => 'web-service-callback-function',
    'access callback' => true, // Allow all users
  );
```

Comment: Thats not what I asked for, I don't even need to create menu to access webserverice call. I just want to embed webservice contents in the existing page.